# undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x0000000764d1b8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

This my code in the index controller.

```
order_customs = Order.select{|order| order.performer.white_label_id==1}
@orders_customs_display=order_customs.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)     
@orders_customs_refunded=order_customs.select{|order| order.refunded==true}.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
order_white_label=Order.select{|order| order.performer.white_label_id!=1}
@orders_white_label_display=order_white_label.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
@orders_white_label_refunded=order_white_label.select{|order| order.refunded==true}.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

I am using will_paginate gem for pagination. I was using it before without any error but when I changed the code from `Order.all.paginate()` to `Order.select{}.paginate()` error is coming.

The error I am getting is

> undefined method `paginate'

I need to paginate those values for showing them in a table. If I can't paginate them, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to include the `will_paginate` method for the data type `Array`.

To do so, include the line

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

at the top of your controller, or in the `ApplicationController` if you need pagination in all of your controllers.

Comment: The tricky thing is if you require it elsewhere in other controller and this one is called before the controller without require then no error is thrown. So don't forget to add it everywhere arrays are paginated or anywhere above e.g. ApplicationController.

Comment: This worked great, just make sure to use it outside the class definition if you are using these in your models.

Answer (score -2):

Removing the .all worked for me.